# How do I use sqlldr to load data from multiple files at once?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I need to load data into an oracle DB using SQLLDR, but I need to pull parts of my table from two different INFILES using the different positions from those infiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly load data from multiple files into a single table and write control files to do that. The format of files should be same. Still running two separate jobs would be a better option. Doing little bit research would help. I have done many extra things using SQL*LOADER.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like two separate jobs would be simplest.

Depending on the file definitions, it may be possible to use a single job. See [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005855) for an idea (except you'd actually have the two record formats loading into the same table rather than different tables).